# Как сделать кнопки с выбором в telebot(Python)

Tags: python, telebot

Есть inline-кнопки `thirtyInterval` `hourInterval` `fiveHourInterval`
Как я могу сделать им функцию выбора, как RadioButton ? Что бы при нажатие на первую кнопку у меня была отмечена как выбранная к примеру в надписи будет эмоджи ✅.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "text")
def instructionsCallback(call):
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)  
    sendTextMessage(call.message) 



#КНОПКИ текста
def sendTextMessage(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1) 
    thirtyInterval = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("30 МИНУТ", callback_data="none")
    hourInterval = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("1 ЧАС", callback_data="none")
    fiveHourInterval = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("5 ЧАСОВ", callback_data="none")
    gonnaBack = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("⬅️ НАЗАД", callback_data="backToStart")
    keyboard.add(thirtyInterval, hourInterval, fiveHourInterval, gonnaBack)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите ваш текст, учитывая интервалы:", reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_message)
```